# Maximum linked model depth?

Tags: linked-data

How deep can you link models in Blender? I mean, what if you were to link model C within model B, which is then linked within model A? Would that work?

[edit]

I'm working with models created in Lego/LDraw, and it could potentially save space if the individual Lego parts were stored outside the model and instanced instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No that would not work, you can only link non linked objects (so just the objects you made) in the file you want to link.

Comment: That's disappointing. In LDraw I have made a hierarchy of nested models. Model C is contained in Model B. In Model A I want to link Model B and treat it as a single object. And so on. :(

Comment: but if model A, model B, model C are all different files you can link them all into a new file. I think this keeps your workflow clean.

Comment: I just tested and it seems you *can* link to a model in a second file, and the second file links to a model in a third file.

Comment: I updated my first post with some additional info about what I'm doing.

Comment: Ok great, I have also tested it but I could only link an object that was made in the file and not the linked object in the file. So I would like to know how you did it.

Comment: I created File A containing Model A. I then created File B and linked to Model A in File A. I then created File C and linked to Model A from File B. I put Model A in a group first if that makes a difference.